# connect to an IP Address through python sockets

Tags: python, ip-address, python-sockets, python-ipaddress

My Device is connected to a router, and i have the IP address and port. now i need a script so that i can connect to that IP Address and port and retrieve the data and display in my computer. The data that my Device sends is XML.

I'm completely new to this.
I ran Wireshark and i could see my device is sending data from an ip address, and i can even verify that the data is right.

i just need to get the data out and feed it to a visualisation application.

```
import socket

# Define the IP address and port
TCP_IP = '192.xx.xx.xx'  # Target server's IP address
TCP_PORT = xxxxx

# Create a socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

try:
    # Connect to the target server
    s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
    print(f"Connected to {TCP_IP}:{TCP_PORT}")

    # Send an HTTP request
    request = b'GET /miners/get?file=BFGMiner-3.99-r.1-win32.zip HTTP/1.1\r\nUser-Agent: MultiMiner/V3\r\nHost: www.multiminerapp.com\r\n\r\n'
    s.send(request)

    # Receive the response
    response = s.recv(1024)  # Adjust buffer size as needed
    with open("http-response.txt", "wb") as respfile:
        respfile.write(response)

except ConnectionRefusedError:
    print("Connection refused. Check the server availability.")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
finally:
    s.close()
```

i have tried using this for now

Comment: Do you know how to make _any_ HTTP request using Python? Is your Device running a web server, and the router forwards a port to that web server?

Comment: No I really dont.

It is a medical device and it is connected to an IP in the router. and the router is in turn connected to my computer through another IP.

Comment: *"i could see my device is sending data"* — Where to? Does the device *send* data to some predetermined address, or is it _waiting for incoming connections_?

Comment: Yes it sends data to a predetermined ipaddress and port.

Comment: Well, then only the machine at that IP address and port can *receive* the data. For that it needs to _listen_ to incoming connections, not establish outgoing connections.

Comment: okay. So can you help me on how to do it?